# Cannot fnid grpcpp/grpcpp.h - how to include it?

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm having trouble installing and including grpc into my C++ program.

Here's what I did to install grpc:

```
$ sudo apt install -y build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config
$ git clone --recurse-submodules -b v1.33.2 https://github.com/grpc/grpc
$ cd grpc
$ mkdir -p cmake/build
$ pushd cmake/build
$ cmake -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON \
      -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$MY_INSTALL_DIR \
      ../..
$ make -j
$ make install
$ popd
```

Then in my own application, I created a file `keyvaluestore.proto`, compiled it and now trying to implement it in the below program. But when I try to compile the program below, it complains that it can't find `grpcpp/grpcpp.h`.

I'm basically almost copying the code from the repo's example:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.33.2/examples/cpp/keyvaluestore/server.cc

```
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include "../protos/keyvaluestore.grpc.pb.h"

using grpc::Server;
using grpc::ServerBuilder;
using grpc::ServerContext;
using grpc::ServerReaderWriter;
using grpc::Status;
using keyvaluestore::KeyValueStore;
using keyvaluestore::Request;
using keyvaluestore::Response;

class KeyValueStoreImpl final : public KeyValueStore::Server {
    Status Get(ServerContext* context, const Request* request) {
        
    }

    Status Put(ServerContext* context, const Request* request) {
        
    }

}
```

I'm then compiling the above program with the following make rule:

```
LDFLAGS = -L ~/.local/include -L ~/.local/lib

backend_server: backend_server.o
    g++ $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

I'm assuming I'm not installing the library properly into my program?

Comment: Where did make install put the header files - /usr/local/include I'd guess? Is /usr/local/include in your default GCC include path? (and /usr/local/lib in the library include path?)

Comment: I assume that's when I called `cmake -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$MY_INSTALL_DIR ../..` right? Because I put it in my `/home` folder. How do I include this folder in my default GCC include path? And what does it mean to "(and /usr/local/lib in the library include path?)"?

Comment: OK, so you have the file in /home/doctopus/include/grpcpp/grpcpp.h ? Try adding `-I ~/include -L ~/lib` to the compile options, probably before the $^.

Comment: So the header files are actually in `/home/doctopus/.local`. I have in my makefile: `LDFLAGS = -I ~/.local/include -L ~/.local/lib` and `g++ $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@`. It's still giving the same error though
`

Comment: So you are saying that `~/.local/include/grpcpp/grpcpp.h` exists?

Comment: Hmm, that looks OK to me. It might be worth trying /home/doctopus instead of ~ in case you haven't already, just in case CMake doesn't pass the ~ into a shell to expand it for some reason, but I'm running out of ideas otherwise. There are a few options you can use to debug header includes too e.g. `g++ $(LDFLAGS) -M rpcpp/grpcpp.h` I think.

Comment: Yes @drescherjm. FWIW, I installed grpc in `/usr/local/` instead and now it's importing and compiling fine.